# Select values from one table based on two other tables (relational)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables one with company details, one with officer details and one that connects those two Company_Officer by ID so I can tell which officer works for which company and he can also work for multiple companies and a company can have multiple workers.

I am trying to create a query that would give me ID of the company that Officer works for company_Id, officers name and his role. The company he works for must have company_index set to FTSE 100 his status officer_resigned must be set to 0 and also he must work for more than 1 company.

Something like:

```
Company_ID|Company_Name|Officer_Name|Officer_Role
--------------------------------------------------
1         |  Apple PLC |Millis, John|Director
1         | Apple PLC  |DLAMINI, Bob|Secretary
2         | Google PLC |Millis, Johm|Secretary
```

Company_Details:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxzUi.png]

Officer_Details:

[image]

Company_Officer:

[image]

I have started fiddling with sql but it does not make much sense to me when it comes to relational databases. I understand that I need to use join. Is it all possible to achieve with one query?

Comment: Simply JOIN the tables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another sql for extra constraint of "getting only those officers which work for more than 1 company".

```
   SELECT cd.company_id,
           cd.company_name,
           od.officer_name,
           co.officer_role
    FROM   COMPANY_DETAILS cd
           inner join COMPANY_OFFICER co
                   ON cd.company_id = co.company_id
           inner join OFFICER_DETAILS od
                   ON co.officer_id = od.officer_id
    WHERE  cd.company_index = 'FTSE 100' AND
           od.officer_resigned = '0' AND
           co.officer_id IN
           ( SELECT officer_id
             FROM   COMPANY_OFFICER
             GROUP  BY officer_id
             HAVING Count( DISTINCT company_id ) > 1 
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    CD.company_id,
    CD.company_name,
    OD.officer_name,
    CO.officer_role
FROM
    company_details CD
INNER JOIN company_officer CO 
   ON CD.company_id = CO.company_id
INNER JOIN officer_details OD 
   ON CO.officer_id = OD.officer_id
WHERE CD.company_index='FTSE 100' AND 
      OD.officer_resigned='0';
```

[image]

Comment: Yes and from this selection only officers that have not resigned so officer_resigned = 0 and only companies with index FTSE 100

Comment: sorry buddy, i forgot to add condition. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: Would it also be possible to only get those officers which work for more than 1 company?

Comment: Yes, why not ! You may go on adding extra checks wherever required.                 I'm adding 1 more comment for your required sql query here, so that it might not divert from the actual question posted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you even need to join?

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Company_ID, c.Company_Name, o.Officer_Name, o.Officer_Role
FROM Company_Details c, Officer_Details o, Company_Officer co
WHERE Company_Index = 'FTSE 100' AND Officer_Resigned = 0 AND co.Officer_ID = o.Officer_ID AND co.Company_ID = c.Company_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use inner join between the 3 table

```
select 
       Company_Details.Company_ID
     , Company_Details.Company_Name
     , Officer_Details.Officer_Name
     , Company_Officer.Officer_Role
from Company_Details
INNER JOIN Officer_Details on Officer_Details.Officer_ID = Company_Officer.Officer_ID
INNER JOIN Company_Officer on Company_Officer.Company_ID = Company_Details.Company_ID;
```

Comment: There seems to be an error with Officer_Details.Officer_id = Company_Officer.Officer_id it says that it couldn't find a column Company_Officer.Officer_id

Comment: Did you remove the second dot, I see scaisEdge type Company_Officer..Officer_id  instead of Company_Officer.Officer_id

Comment: The second dot wasn't the problem (I have seen it earlier and fixed). Unknown column 'Company_Officer.Officer_id' in 'on clause'  still occurs

Comment: There way two id lower case and i have change the answer with Company_Officer.Officer_ID upper case .. the column name is from your schema ..